# Angular attribute for HTML stream

Tags: angular, video-streaming, cloudflare, cloudflarestream

I am trying to add a video from cloudflare stream into my website. The code that cloudflare gives runs in html but when I paste the code in the html component of my angular project. I am getting the error -

> Error: Template parse errors:
>       'stream' is not a known element:
>       1. If 'stream' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>       2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
>         
>       
>       [ERROR ->]

The code that works in html looks like this

```html
    <stream src="6aaee8579a7a************" autoplay muted preload></stream>
    <script data-cfasync="false" defer="" type="text/javascript" src="https://embed.cloudflarestream.com/embed/r4xu.fla9.latest.js?video=6aaee8579a7a************"></script>
```

Now this is really a POC, and I myself dont really know angular, just trying to learn. Could someone please direct me to the correct material that I should look into to sort this?

Comment: Is `stream` some new HTML tag? Angular doesn't know that tag and throws the error. You can either change tag name or create simple component with selector `stream` or add NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA to @NgModule.schemas as the error states

Comment: I guess so? after all the code runs just fine when I create a normal html file. @yurzui

Comment: Can you please share the specification on that tag?

Comment: Here is the whole schema Angular uses https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/f74e0fd8251802107094886d76a0971d478d6be8/packages/compiler/src/schema/dom_element_schema_registry.ts#L78-L232 It includes `<audio>` and `<video>` tags but not `<stream>`

Comment: @RickRoy have you tried replacing `<stream></stream>` with `<video></video>` to see if the error goes away and stream works?

Comment: @AsimHashmi <video></video> doesn't work

Comment: @yurzui it seems like that <stream> is something the cloudflare js uses to inject the video into. I guess the way forward for me is to create my own custom component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following steps to add cloudflare stream to your Angular component:

**1**. Add the stream tags to your required component.

app.component.html

```
<stream src="5d5bc37ffcf54c9b82e996823bffbb81" controls></stream>
```

**2**. Now your `AppModule` (assuming your component belongs to `AppModule`) should be like this:

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ], // <- You need to add this line
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**3**. Now add the cloudflare javascript library to your `index.html`

```
<html>
  <body>
    <my-app>loading</my-app>
  </body>

  <script src="https://embed.cloudflarestream.com/embed/r4xu.fla9.latest.js" id="video_embed" defer="" async=""></script>  
</html>
```

You can find the working **stackblitz** demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-idsmai)